# Upcasting in SystemVerilog

Tags: system-verilog

I'm trying to understand Upcasting and Downcasting in SystemVerilog.
Upcasting is casting to a supertype, while downcasting is casting to a subtype.
Upcasting is always allowed, but Downcasting involves a type check.

So I made a simple test code for upcasting and downcasting.

1.Test for upcasting.

```
class animal;
  function void eat();
    $display("eat");
  endfunction
endclass

class dog extends animal;
  function void bark();
    $display("woof");
  endfunction
endclass

class cat extends animal;
  function void meow();
    $display("meow");
  endfunction
endclass

module test;
  animal a1,a2;
  dog d1, d2;
  cat c1, c2;
  initial begin

    a1=new();
    d1=new();
    c1=new();
    
    d1.eat();
    c1.eat();
    
    d1.bark();
    c1.meow();
    
    c1 = d1;
    c1.bark(); //bark is not a class item.
    
    d1 = c1;
    d1.meow(); //meow is not a class item.
    
    a1 = d1;
    a1.bark(); //bark is not a class item.
    
    a1 = c1;
    a1.meow(); //meow is not a class item.
    
    
  end
endmodule
```

In the class animal, dog and cat, I need to use `bark` and `meow` function from a derived `dog` and `meow` class. So I declared as the below But I got the compile error

```
    c1 = d1;
    c1.bark(); //bark is not a class item.
    d1 = c1;
    d1.meow(); //meow is not a class item.
    a1 = d1;
    a1.bark(); //bark is not a class item.
    a1 = c1;
    a1.meow(); //meow is not a class item.
```

As I know, the base class want/need to a properties from a derived class then we do `upcasting`. How do I get `c1's bark()`, `d1's meow()`, `a1's bark()`, `a1.meow()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you comment out all the lines *after* `c1 = d1;`, you get a more helpful error message:

```
    c1 = d1;
          |
xmvlog: *E,TYCMPAT: assignment operator type check failed 
(expecting datatype compatible with 'class $unit::cat' but found 
'class $unit::dog' instead).
```

This gives you the reason why `bark` is not a class item: the assignment failed because `c1` is not the same **type** as `d1`.

The VCS simulator behaves the same way, and produces a similar compile error.